# Session.getTemporaryActiveUserKey() keeps changing

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

My understanding from [the docs](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getTemporaryActiveUserKey()) is that `Session.getTemporaryActiveUserKey()` changes for a user every 30 days. In my past experience using it, this was true but over the past couple of days  it is now changing and can no longer be relied on to change only every 30 days. I have a custom formula that I called repeatedly for just myself and logged the result of `Session.getTemporaryActiveUserKey()` here:

```
2022-05-03 19:27:25.606 MDT key AZPrZfeo+F6LjIDVp
2022-05-03 19:27:25.697 MDT key AZPrZfeo+F6LjIDVp
2022-05-03 19:27:25.809 MDT key AZPrZfeo+F6LjIDVp
2022-05-03 19:27:25.827 MDT key AZPrZfeo+F6LjIDVp
2022-05-03 19:27:25.830 MDT key AZPrZfeo+F6LjIDVp
2022-05-03 19:27:25.890 MDT key AIPNip3sEIA371wT
2022-05-03 19:27:25.892 MDT key AIPNip3sEIA371wT
2022-05-03 19:27:25.926 MDT key AZPrZfeo+F6LjIDVp
2022-05-03 19:27:25.929 MDT key AZPrZfeo+F6LjIDVp
2022-05-03 19:27:25.973 MDT key AZPrZfeo+F6LjIDVp
```

Am I reading the docs wrong or did Google change something?

Comment: I have been testing and it seems to linger so far. I only encounter the value given. Tested as a custom function and regular function in the script, same behavior. Is there anything you've done differently that can cause it to change temporarily? Maybe that is from another script that does the same thing as this is unique per script.

Comment: For what purpose are you logging the value for?

Comment: @OctaviaSima for debugging

Comment: @OctaviaSima this is the only script where I have debugged it like that

Comment: When I log mine, it just shows the long raw key, while yours show `MDT key` appended with a shorter version. How do you achieve that? Was this somewhat encrypted? Can you show how it's done?

Comment: And also how often does this happen? Is it a rare occurence but at regular interval? or just that instance?

Comment: It happens ALL the time since early May. I've been observing it everyday since then and on multiple users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observed the same - ID changing between 2 values. Only visible since 2nd of May for me. AND - one of the two IDs I get is the same since more than 30 days!

I created a issue in Googles tracker: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/231606423
Thanks for starring it!